# Convex hull of some points on the convex position

Tags: algorithms, convex-hulls

**Definition**:

The [Convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a set of points is the smallest convex set which contains them.

**Question**:

> Assume that $n$ points like $P=\{p_0,p_1,p_2,...,p_{n-1}\}$ are given
>   and all we know is that they belong to the boundary of $CH(P)$. How can we compute
>   $CH(P)$ in $O(n)$ time?

**My try**:

I know that there is [an algorithm](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs601/Melkman.html) for computing the convex hull of a set of points in $O(n)$ time. But that's a more general case. I wonder how we can use the property that all of the points are on the boundary of the convex hull to build the algorithm. As far as I know, including every kind of sorting would take a time of $O(nlogn)$, since sorting cannot be done in less than that. So, we should somehow get rid of sorting. Another related interesting question would be that if someone gives me some edges on the convex position, how can I build the convex hull out of that?

Note: All of the points are in 2D space. The output should be something like the clockwise order of points which make the convex hull.

Comment: What do you want as output of the computation? You already know all the vertices and some other points. Do you want the subset of vertices? Equations for the facets? It may not matter, but what dimension are the points in?

Comment: @EthanBolker All of the points are in 2D space. The problem is that they don't have any kind of order. For example, they're not clockwise or sth like that. So, if we provide such an order for the convex hull, we're done

Comment: There may be something helpful in the _rubber band algorithm_ literature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670932/convex-hull-solving-using-a-rubber-band

Comment: Your phrasing fooled me, for a few minutes I was wondering why I never knew 2D convex hulls could be computed in linear time... Turns out that Melkman's algorithm only works for simple polygonal chains. If you don't have a similar ordering property on your input, I'm not sure whether a linear complexity can be reached.

Answer (score 1):

With the current phrasing, what you ask for can only be done if there exists a sorting algorithm for real numbers that runs in linear time.

Given $n$ real numbers $t_1, \ldots, t_n$, shift and rescale them to fit in the interval $[0, \pi]$. This gives you real numbers $\theta_1,\ldots, \theta_n$ whose order match the original $t_i$'s. Consider the 2D point $p_i$ with coordinates $(\cos\theta_i, \sin\theta_i)$. Every $p_i$ belongs to the boundary of their convex hull.

If you find a counter clock wise ordering of the points $p_i$'s, you have effectively sorted the original numbers $t_i$'s. Since the transformation from number to point takes linear time, the method you're asking for would allow sorting in linear time.

Now as far as I know, the $O(n\log n)$ bound for sorting algorithms only applies to comparison-based sorts. A common example of sort algorithm that isn't compatison-based would be the radix sort for integers, but that one relies on specific properties of integers.

Maybe someone somewhere will one day come up with an actual solution to your question, but you're unlikely to get one anytime soon.

Comment: So, you're saying that the fact that we know the points are on the boundary of the convex hull does not help us? I thought that's a huge assumption!

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh If I put in a little more effort, I can formally prove that solving your problem is equivalent to sorting real numbers (my current answer only sketches half of that proof). From there, the conclusion depends on what you believe (or prove) is possible. I personally don't think there exists a general linear sorting algorithm, so with that premise, your assumption doesn't help. In fact to me, having a simple polygonal chain is a much bigger assumption than being part of the boundary of the convex hull. In the link for the Melkman algorithm you've provided, there are some...

Comment: ... pictures illustrating where a new point of the simple chain can be located. That new point can either be discarded (yellow), replace the previous point in the CCW order (blue), or come right before/after the previous point (red/green). But the point cannot appear in the white area. That's a structural property tied to simple chains. The Melkman algorithm algorithm only works thanks to that property. Now if you remove that simple chain assumption, you have to deal with points in the white area, and that completely breaks the linear complexity. Specifically, if you look into theoretical...

Comment: ... complexity bounds for general 2D convex hulls algorithms, the optimal lower bound is usually $O(n\log k)$, where $k$ is the size of the hull. That's why I was surprised to learn there was a linear algorithm, until I realized the input had to be structured beforehand. (On a side note, building a simple polygonal chain from an arbitrary list of points would require a form of sorting.)